# I installed 30,000 fonts, now my computer is a slug. How do I remove them?

Tags: windows-8, fonts

This served great for the project I was working on but now it's slowing me down too much. I've tried going to %windir%\fonts and ordering them by date modified so I would delete all of the ones that were installed yesterday but they all weirdly show the same date from the first to the last file. I can't uninstall them all because the system is already using some of them and I wouldn't want to lose Helvetica for example. I've tried to search for the default names to back them up but they simply don't show up, I don't know why, probably because there's just so much stuff up there now, every search takes ages to get done. So I don't know what to do. Selecting fonts on Word now force closes it. Not good. I'm on Win 8 x64

EDIT: searching by the search field is taking ages so I just type the name of the font while having any file in the fonts folder selected then it takes me to the right front. Looking for e.g. Consolas takes me to it and the file's properties have an appropriate date but they're not being ordered by it and it's almost impossible now to search over 30,000 fonts and pick the Win default ones

Comment: Microsoft link: [Fonts supplied with Windows 8](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=164)

Comment: I couldn't find a download pack on this. I can't download them all

Comment: Make a backup of all 30.000 fonts, delete the complete original fonts folder, open CMD window (right-click » run as admin), type `SFC / SCANNOW`. Windows has a backup of all system fonts under C:\Windows\WinSXS, but you can't just search for them and copy them over. You have to use System file checker utility. [Read more](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111219195210AAsJSDJ)

Comment: Upvoting just for the slug metaphor - have you tried salt? Unless its a Neptunian slug, in which case definitely don't use salt.

Comment: Scan is done, nixda. What should I do now? winged, look for "caracol babosa" on youtube, I wouldn't wanna do that to my precious computer ;)

Comment: Tom, I can't help but laugh here... This is the sort of thing that if you brought me your computer I would laugh, in your face... and simultaneously feel bad because there was a time each of us would have probably done the same thing! I know its no help... but don't ever do 30,000 things to your computer all at once.

Comment: I had 1500 just fine and my computer is very powerful so I gave it a shot. Still I can't deny the warning flag was raised and I've ignored in the name of science :-)

Answer (score 4):

I've erased %windir%\fonts\*.* in cmd and it just prevented me to erase the ones that were being used. Rebooted and installed a random MS software and some of my favorite fonts, especially Pragmata Pro, and now it's all good again. Still hoping for a more elegant solution.

Pro-tip: Don't install 30,000 fonts on your computer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Open `Windows Explorer` and type `*.ttf datemodified/datecreated:yesterdaysdate`

That should find the fonts you need to delete.

Comment: that's the whole issue. I've tried grouping them instead of sorting to get a better visualization but all of the fonts are modified/created at oldest by yesterday. Some are grouped by "sometime in the future"(?) although their properties show their right modification date (yesterday). I've edit the question a little bit if you want to take a look.

Comment: Oh right. What if you change datemodified to datecreated?

Comment: Both are the same, I've tried it

Comment: What about deleting them all and downloading the original Win8 fonts as suggest by @nixda above?

Comment: There isn't a download pack and I can't sort through the default ones from the new ones.

Comment: Hmmmm. That is a problem. A system restore won't help here and I don't have any other suggestions I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks for trying to help. Suggestion: don't install 30,000 fonts ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. View fonts in details style
2. Sort by designer/foundry
3. Delete all fonts which are not made by microsoft corporation

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score -1):

So I also installed a ton of extra fonts that ended up causing me problems. My solution was to add a "file names" sort by (right click the sort bar). I then deleted all the ones that resided in my appdata folder.